# Making a display board in console using c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to make a display board that takes a `char`and displays it in a specified location. The following is the code showing what i did to "draw" the board.

```
const int height = 3;
const int width = 10;
char board[width][height];

void draw()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            if (!(x == 9))
            {
                cout << board[y][x];
            }
            else
            {
                cout << board[y][x] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if i create a function to fill the array with 'a' to test it and call `draw()`, it runs fine and this is the result i get

```
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
aaaaaaaaaa
```

The fill array function:

```
void fillarray()
{
    for (int a = 0; a < height; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < width; b++)
        {
            board[a][b] = 'a';
        }
    }
}
```

However, if i try to specify a location using the following function, the result is a mess

```
void write(char c, int x, int y)
{
    board[y][x] = c;
}
```

How i called `write()`

```
write('a', 1, 1);
```

So i must be doing something wrong in the `write` function but i cant figure out what since i am kinda new to c++. Also thanks in advance for helping.

Edit: Felt like it would help if i included the result i get when i call `write()`

```
    a
 a
```

Comment: nit: bad form is `if (!(x == 9))`.  Better: `if (x != 9)`

Comment: Your inner loop statement could be simplified to `cout << board[y][x] << ((x==9)?endl:"");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your board is declared as:

```
char board[width][height];
```

But you are writing to the board array like this:

```
cout << board[y][x];
```

Where "y" is your height variable and "x" is your width variable. I think you have your index variables for the 2-d array reversed.  Don't your really mean say.

```
cout << board[x][y];
```

All your assignment statements in your other functions have the same bug.

Or better yet, so you don't have to fix all your code, just declare board as:

```
char board[height][width];
```

Also, some code style changes to improve your code.

Instead of this:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        if (!(x == 9))
        {
            cout << board[y][x];
        }
        else
        {
            cout << board[y][x] << endl;
        }
    }
```

This:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        cout << board[y][x];
    }
    cout << endl;
```

Comment: Ohk i see i was just being stupid and needed a break. Thankss

Comment: I fixed it by doing " char board[height][width];" opposed to  " char board[width][height];"

Comment: Yep.  That's probably the better fix since a 2-d array is `array[HEIGHT][WIDTH]`

Comment: And I left you another style comment.